# Existence of at least one point of continuity of the limit function of a sequence of continuous functions on closed interval.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence

I saw the title statement in a Chinese translation of a Russian book, and I put doubt on it, so it's impossible to find companions or solutions. Since it's quite weird, and I can think of an example that *may or may not* be a counterexample (I can't prove the validity of it).

Imagine the sequence of all rationals: $r_1,r_2,...,r_n,....$ Now construct $f_n(x):=1$ at $r_1,r_2,...,r_n$, and have a V shape between $2$ successive $r$'s arranged from small to large. For instance, take $r_1=0,r_1=1,r_2=1/2,$ then my construction is $$f_2(x)=\begin{cases}|4x-1| & x\in[0,1/2],\\|4x-3| & x\in[1/2,1].\end{cases}$$
Then we take $F_n(x)=f_n(x)^n.$
I'm expecting $f_n$ to run all over the rationals, and results in 1's in the limit of $F_n,$ while the irrationals are less than $1$ and raising to the power of $n$ makes it go to zero.

But wait, I can't guarantee that the $f_n(\text{irrational})$ is less than a number that is strictly less than one, *i.e.*: I can't prove that the $F_n(\text{irrational})$ tends to zero as $n\to\infty.$

Can you prove or disprove the statement in the title? Thanks.

Comment: General fact: Let $X$ a topological space, and $f_n \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of continuous functions. If $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ exists for all $x\in X$, then the set of points $x\in X$ where $f$ is discontinuous is meagre in $X$. Since a closed interval $[a,\,b]$ is a Baire space, it is not meagre in itself (and the set of points where $f$ is continuous is dense).

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm sorry that I don't know much topology,so your general fact is a bit of confusing for me. Can u pls make it simpler,with a simple yes-or-no answer to the statement in my title?(I **do** accept axiom of choice, if it concerns)Thx

Comment: The short answer is: a pointwise limit of continuous functions is continuous at _most_ points of the interval. Every subinterval $(\alpha-\varepsilon,\alpha+\varepsilon)$ consists "almost entirely" of points of continuity of the limit function.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the counterexample. Are you trying to prove that $F_n(x)$ converges to 1 if $x$ is rational and to $0$ if it is irrational?

Comment: To Giuseppe ,affirmative answer.

Comment: To Daniel, when you say"at most" do you mean converge "almost everywhere"?

Comment: @Wilson of Gordon do you know the title of this russian book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel points out, there is a general fact, but let me try to give a bit more details on a possible proof. Let $C_N = \{x\in[a,b]:|f_n|\leq N\textrm{ for all }n\}$. Since all $f_n$ are continuous, each set $C_N$ is closed. Then as $\sup_n|f_n(x)|$ is finite for any $x$, the interval $[a,b]$ can be written as the union of all $C_N$ as $N$ runs over all natural numbers. Now Baire's theorem says that at least one of $C_N$ contains an open interval. This means that there is an open interval on which the family $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded. I leave the rest as an exercise.

Note that the above argument is usually called the *uniform boundedness principle*, because it derives uniform boundedness from pointwise boundedness.
Let us recall Baire's theorem here.

**Baire's theorem.** *Let $\{C_N\}$ be a countable collection of closed subsets of $[a,b]$
such that $\bigcup_N C_N=[a,b]$.
Then at least one of $C_N$ contains a nontrivial interval,
i.e., there exist $N$, $x\in [a,b]$, and $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset C_N$.*

*Proof.* Suppose that $C_N$ does not contain any open interval, for any $N$.
This means that any open interval $I$ in $[a,b]$ contains a point from $[a,b]\setminus
C_N$, and so $I\cap([a,b]\setminus C_N)$ contains a nontrivial closed
interval, because $[a,b]\setminus C_N$ is open (relative to $[a,b]$).
Applying this with $I=(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon<1$,
we obtain $x_1\in [a,b]$ and $\varepsilon_1\in(0,1)$ such that
$[x_1-\varepsilon_1,x_1+\varepsilon_1]\subset [a,b]\setminus C_1$.
Similarly, there are $x_2\in [a,b]$ and $\varepsilon_2\in(0,
\frac12)$ such that 
$$
[x_2-\varepsilon_2,x_2+\varepsilon_2]\subset (x_1-\varepsilon_1,x_1+\varepsilon_1) \cap
([a,b]\setminus C_2),
$$
and so on,
we get a sequence of intervals $(x_k-\varepsilon_k,x_k+\varepsilon_k)$ such that $\varepsilon_k\in(0,
\frac1k)$ and 
$$
[x_k-\varepsilon_k,x_k+\varepsilon_k]\subset (x_{k-1}-\varepsilon_{k-1},x_{k-1}+\varepsilon_{k-1}) \cap
([a,b]\setminus C_k).
$$
In particular, we have $x_k\in [x_n-\varepsilon_n,x_n+\varepsilon_n]$ for $k>n$,
hence $\{x_k\}$ is Cauchy, and by completeness, there is $x\in [a,b]$ such
that $x_k\to x$.
By closedness, we have $x\in [x_n-\varepsilon_n,x_n+\varepsilon_n]$ for all $n$,
and since $[x_n-\varepsilon_n,x_n+\varepsilon_n]\subset [a,b]\setminus C_n$,
we have shown that there is $x\in [a,b]$ such that $x\not\in C_n$
for all $n$.

Comment: That sounds interesting, but I've not learnt much topology yet,in fact, only up to Heine-borel theorem. So what does Baire's theorem states? Google doesn't make it quite clear.Thx

Comment: @WilsonZhao: Baire's theorem (in this context) states that if the interval $[a,b]$ is the union of countably many closed sets then at least one of those sets must contain a nontrivial interval.

Comment: Thank you so much timur. This is the first time to use this site, and you guys make me feel so thankful.